# Is there a maven property set by Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Question is quite simple, in fact.

I tend to remember having seen here answers to maven/jenkins questions explaining that it is possible to activate some portions of a maven build in Jenkins by activating those profiles using a property, given by Jenkins when it starts the maven build.

But what is the name of that Jenkins property ? And which is that property value ?

Comment: I generally just use a -PjenkinsBuild type mechanism to turn on a profile for a build server.  I like the explicit nature of it.

Comment: Agreed. While it's possible to activate a profile using environment variables I think it's must simpler to just explicit set the profile when calling Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a profile which will be automatcially be activated by an environment variable in Jenkins.

You can use one of the following for example JENKINS_HOME or JENKINS_URL to activate a profile:

```
BUILD_NUMBER
    The current build number, such as "153"
BUILD_ID
    The current build id, such as "2005-08-22_23-59-59" (YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm-ss)
JOB_NAME
    Name of the project of this build, such as "foo" or "foo/bar"
BUILD_TAG
    String of "jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}". Convenient to put into a resource file, a jar file, etc for easier identification.
EXECUTOR_NUMBER
    The unique number that identifies the current executor (among executors of the same machine) that's carrying out this build. This is the number you see in the "build executor status", except that the number starts from 0, not 1.
NODE_NAME
    Name of the slave if the build is on a slave, or "master" if run on master
NODE_LABELS
    Whitespace-separated list of labels that the node is assigned.
WORKSPACE
    The absolute path of the directory assigned to the build as a workspace.
JENKINS_HOME
    The absolute path of the directory assigned on the master node for Jenkins to store data.
JENKINS_URL
    Full URL of Jenkins, like http://server:port/jenkins/
BUILD_URL
    Full URL of this build, like http://server:port/jenkins/job/foo/15/
JOB_URL
    Full URL of this job, like http://server:port/jenkins/job/foo/
SVN_REVISION
    Subversion revision number that's currently checked out to the workspace, such as "12345"
SVN_URL
    Subversion URL that's currently checked out to the workspace.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing that a bit differently. E.g. if I want to start integration tests via Jenkins, I have a profile which starts and stops the integration test server:

```
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test-wrapper</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>ci</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        ...
```

In the **Jenkins Build Config** (Goals and Options) I just add the parameter `-Dci`

Which will activate that profile.